# .bashrc syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, bashrc

Everytime I run terminal I get this error message ".bashrc syntax error: unexpected end of file"

So I started commenting parts of it to know the issue and I guess it was in the below if condition. I wonder how I can edit it to work?

```
if ("1" == "$?LD_LIBRARY_PATH") then
        if ("$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" !~ */usr/local/iscir/lib*) then
                export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/iscir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        endif
else
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/iscir/lib
endif
```

I tried this but didn't work as

```
if ["1" == "$?LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]; then
        if ["$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" !~ */usr/local/iscir/lib*]; then
                export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/iscir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        fi
else
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/iscir/lib
fi
```

Comment: run it though `shellcheck`. (`apt install shellcheck` to install on debian based system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `endif` in bash. An `if` statement is ended by a `fi`. Also, when using the `[ ]` test construct, you need a space around the `[`. The `=~` regex match operator, requires bash's special `[[ ]]` instead of the POSIX `[ ]`, and to negate the match, you negate the whole test (`[[ ! foo ~ bar ]]`), you can't use `!~`. Also, it requires a regular expression, not a shell glob. So `*` doesn't mean anything by itself, you need `.*` for "any character". Then, the format for setting and exporting a variable is `export foo=bar` and also, you have a stray `?` between the `$` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So try this:

```
if [ "1" == "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
    if [[ ! "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" =~ .*/usr/local/iscir/lib.* ]]; then
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/iscir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    fi
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/iscir/lib"
fi
```

That should work, but the whole thing doesn't make sense. When will `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` be `1`? I don't really see how this would ever be executed. If all you want to do is add `/usr/local/iscir/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if it isn't there already, you just need this:

```
if [ -z "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/iscir/lib"
elif [[ ! "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" == */usr/local/iscir/lib* ]]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/iscir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
fi
```

Comment: The "stray" `?` is part of csh's `$?name` substitution form, which will expand to `1` the `name` is set, and to `0` if it isn't.

Comment: Nope. That's broken. Unlike the original, that will set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to `/tmp/iscir/path:` if it wasn't already set, which will **add the current working directory** to it, leading to **DLL Injections**.

Comment: @mosvy fair point. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit it:

- The command `[` needs space on both sides, like all other commands
- The comparison operator `=~` is not part of `test`. You need the command `[[` instead.
- You are missing an `=` sign when setting the export value (twice)
- Your test `"1" == "$?LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` will always be false

If you just want to extend the path if it does not already contain the expansion, you can use this instead:

```
case "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" in
    */usr/local/iscir/lib*);;
    *)
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/iscir/lib:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
        ;;
esac
```